# mysql add column for hour difference between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, group-concat

I have edited a mysql table here in SQLfiddle: [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/245f1/41)

As you can see there, i would like to add a column for calculating the difference bewtween the time column and NOW() in hours but nothing is working well.

Any hints?

Comment: Would converting the dates to UNIX timestamps, performing the calculation, and dividing the result by 3600 give you what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * ,HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(Arbeitsbeginn, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s'), NOW()))
FROM (SELECT DRIVERNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsbeginn', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsbeginn', 
             GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'Arbeitsende', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Arbeitsende', 
             GROUP_CONCAT(IF(ACTIONTEXT = 'PB', DATETIME, NULL)) AS 'Projektbeginn' 
      FROM geoImportRoot
      GROUP BY DRIVERNAME
     ) A;
```

Check this [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/245f1/51)

**Output:**

```
|     DRIVERNAME |       ARBEITSBEGINN | ARBEITSENDE |       PROJEKTBEGINN | HOUR(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(ARBEITSBEGINN, '%D.%M.%Y %H:%I:%S'), NOW())) |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Marx, Ronald | 18.06.2013 06:32:09 |      (null) | 18.06.2013 06:32:12 |                                                                     77 |
| Richter, Mario | 18.06.2013 06:42:06 |      (null) | 18.06.2013 06:42:09 |                                                                     77 |
| Winkler, Mario | 18.06.2013 06:48:22 |      (null) |              (null) |                                                                     77 |
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are probably wisest to store your timestamps in `DATETIME` format, not as text.  If you specify your timestamps in a textual form such as '2013-06-18 14:32:09' then MySQL will automatically understand them and translate them to `DATETIME` objects.

If you do this you can index your `DATETIME` fields.  When you have a million transportation jobs in your system, this will help you maintain performance for your application.

Second, the function `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, NOW(), timestamp)` will yield an integer number of hours.   You may wish to use `(1.0/3600.0) * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), timestamp)` instead so you can account for fractional hours.

Thirdly, the integrity of the summary query you presented in your sqlfiddle depends on each worker only having one job in the database. As soon as Herr Richter drives more than once, he will have an Arbeitsbeginn result that looks something like this:

```
 18.06.2013 06:42:06,19.06.2013 06:27:48
```

Comment: well yesm this is the problem right know. i have this new fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44487/7 showing the problem. any suggestions how i can solve this issue?

Comment: You're attempting a pivot operation, so-called because you're pivoting information from rows of your log table to columns of a result set. You need to figure out an unambiguous way of associating Artbeitsbeginn, Arbeitsende, and PB log entries for each particular task. I respectfully suggest you start a new SO question for this new topic.